# How to select maximum of 10 data out of 10,000 from mysql randomly, i.e one at a time using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Goodday all, please am developing an online game like 'who want to be a millionaire'. I have 10,000 questions with answers, in mysql database and I want the players to answer 10 shufled questions but one at a time with timer.At the end of the ten questions the page should echo number of questions answered correctly. Mysql table look does:

```
question_id  question  optiona  optionb  optionc  optiond  answer
```

I have tried the following but no limitation to the number of questions

I will appreciate it, if anyone could reply soonest.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mysql order by rand function

Eg: [General Sample](http://www.paperplanes.de/2008/4/24/mysql_nonos_order_by_rand.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the table becomes too big there is a faster way to do it:

http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2008/06/07/fetching-random-rows-of-mysql-efficiently